# CXF WSDL2Java -p has invalid character exception

Tags: java, unix, cxf, wsdl2java

I'm stuck with generating java classes of a wsdl wit CXF wsdlToJava and because we have a newer version of a WSDL i want to use CXF like the previous developer.

**Im getting an error after executing the following command in my terminal:**
sudo ~/opt/apache-cxf-3.1.12/bin/wsdl2java -verbose -d ./src-gen -p http://www.text.nl/text/UPPERCASETEXT/003 -b ./src/META-INF/bindings-text.xml -validate ./scr/META-INF/Text_UPPERCASETEXT003.wsdl

**After executing i get the following error:**

```
org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.parser.BadUsageException: -p has invalid character!

    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.AbstractToolContainer.execute(AbstractToolContainer.java:180)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.AbstractCXFToolContainer.execute(AbstractCXFToolContainer.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:413)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:105)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.main(WSDLToJava.java:185)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.parser.BadUsageException: -p has invalid character!
```

What character are they are talking about...?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is exactly as stated, in **-p** part, i.e. in `-p http://www.text.nl/text/UPPERCASETEXT/003`.

Documentation about *wsdl2java* tool in CXF is given on web page:
https://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html

The syntax of **-p** option is:
`-p [ wsdl-namespace= ] PackageName`

Description for it states:
*Specifies zero, or more, package names to use for the generated code. Optionally specifies the WSDL namespace to package name mapping.*

In practice, it means that you should either specify one Java package to be used for all generated code, e.g.
`-p nl.text.text.uppercase`,
or you should specify a mapping of one namespace (http://www.text.nl/text/UPPERCASETEXT/003) to a corresponding Java package (*nl.text.text.uppercase*), like
`-p http://www.text.nl/text/UPPERCASETEXT/003=nl.text.text.uppercase`

Of course, if you need to map multiple namespaces to multiple packages, it can be specified with multiple -p options, like:
`-p http://www.text.nl/text/UPPERCASETEXT/003=nl.text.text.uppercase -p http://www.text.nl/text/LOWERCASETEXT/003=nl.text.text.lowercase`